# How to consume a nested multipart/mixed mime type in jersey

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey

I have googled for a long time, but no answer. I hope someone can help me.

Say, I received a multipart/mixed package in jersey server side, its structure looks like this:

```
multipart/mixed
   |
   |---Title: text/plain
   |
   |---Text content: text/plain
   |
   |---Image content: multipart/mixed
   |      |
   |      |--- Image name: text/plain
   |      |
   |      |--- Image body: image/jpeg
   |
   |.........
```

The first two bodypart can be easily processed by using **bodypart.getEntityAs(Class clazz)** method. But for the nested multipart, i can only get a BodyPartEntity and through it get an inputstream. Obviously, it is not easy getting the image name and image body through the inputstream. **So, how can i get the original multipart/mixed entity or what is the right way to process the nested multipart/mixed type in jersey?**

Comment: Should I write a MessageBodyReader by myself?

Comment: finally i found the error. The nested multipart must have boundary in the header and not the same with the parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i found the error. The nested multipart must have boundary in the header and not the same with the parent.