# How to consume nested MultiParts in Jersey?

Tags: java, http, jersey, mime, multipart

I am trying to write a REST endpoint that receives multiple files (as input streams) and data about those files (as Json).

**Here's my client:**

```
public void doSomething() {
MultiPart parent = new MultiPart(MultiPartMediaTypes.createMixed());
MultiPart child = new MultiPart(MultiPartMediaTypes.createMixed());
child.bodyPart(new BodyPart(someObject, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE));
child.bodyPart(new StreamDataBodyPart(someInputStream));
child.bodyPart(new StreamDataBodyPart(someOtherInputStream));
BodyPart bp = new BodyPart(child, MultiPartMediaTypes.createMixed());
parent.bodyPart(bp);
client.post(Entity.entity(parent, MultiPartMediaTypes.createMixed());
}
```

**Here's my server:**

```
@POST
@Path("something")
@Consumes(MultiPartMediaTypes.MULTIPART_MIXED)
public Response multiPart( @Context HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, 
MultiPart multiPart) {

List<BodyPart> bodyParts = multiPart.getBodyParts();

for(BodyPart bp : bodyParts) {
MultiPart multiPart = (MultiPart)bp.getEntity();
}
}
```

Ideally, I should be able to receive the read Entity on that bodyPart as a MultiPart. I should be able to access the underlying multipart. But I get a class cast exception (because the Entity is a BodyPartEntity).

However, on the receiving side, I get a MultiPart which contains a bodyPart whose entity is a BodyPartEntity which only provides an InputStream. The input stream contains all of the contents of the nested MultiPart, but ideally I should just be able to receive it as a MultiPart and read directly from there.

The input Stream looks something like this:

```
--Boundary_3_1589640004_1523988834754

Content-Type: application/json
{"someJson" : "value"}

--Boundary_3_1589640004_1523988834754

Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Disposition: form-data; filename="test.txt"; name="test.txt"
(a bunch of characters representing the image)

--Boundary_3_1589640004_1523988834754
```

These 2 questions are asking exactly what I am asking, yet neither of them seem to work for me

[How to consume a nested multipart/mixed mime type in jersey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16175597/how-to-consume-a-nested-multipart-mixed-mime-type-in-jersey?rq=1)

[Jersey reading nested Multipart (multipart/mixed)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43197019/jersey-reading-nested-multipart-multipart-mixed/43198227#43198227)

How can I easily access the underlying MultiPart without having to manually parse through the InputStream? What am I missing?